# How to parse a single line json file containing multiple objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to read some JSON data for processing. I have a single line file that has multiple JSON objects how can I parse this?

I want the output to be a file with a single line per object.

I have tried a brute force method that will use json.loads recursively to check if the json is valid but I'm getting different results every time I run the program

```
import json

with open('sample.json') as inp:
s = inp.read()

jsons = []

start, end = s.find('{'), s.find('}')
while True:
 try:
    jsons.append(json.loads(s[start:end + 1]))
    print(jsons)
except ValueError:
    end = end + 1 + s[end + 1:].find('}')
else:
    s = s[end + 1:]
    if not s:
        break
    start, end = s.find('{'), s.find('}')

for x  in jsons:
  writeToFilee(x)
```

The json format can be seen here
https://pastebin.com/DgbyjAG9

Comment: Paste a sample of your file along with how you'd like to have the output.

Comment: You want to replace the `taxi_group_id` with what?

Comment: I want to split the single line file containing multiple objects to a multiple line file containing an object on each line

Comment: @Jessica are these objects delimited somehow? Or is it just like {...}{...}?
I found only 1 occurrence of "}\s*{" regex in the paste you provided, am I right to assume this file contains 2 different JSON objects, or are there more?

Comment: how about `jsons = s.replace('}{', '}|{').split('|')` to create a list of json strings?

Comment: @AleksanderZień They are not delimited at all and there are 1200 objects alltogether

Comment: What is the output which you are expecting ?

Comment: @Jessica I have prepared some draft of a solution using approach described in Chris' comment, but the answer given by Sam Mason should solve your issue for good. :)

Comment: BTW, the sample data has *exactly 2* top-level JSON objects. This can be verified manually at jsonlint.com. Click "Validate JSON". It pretty prints, and stops at line 1405. That is the end of the first JSON object. Delete everything through that "}". "Validate JSON" again - the rest of the file is the second JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked for me:

```
import json
with open(input_file_path) as f_in: 
    file_data = f_in.read() 
    file_data = file_data.replace("}{", "},{") 
    file_data = "[" + file_data + "]"
    data = json.loads(file_data)
```

Answer (score 4):

why not just use the `pos` attribute of the [`JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) to tell you where to delimit things?

something like:

```
import json

def json_load_all(buf):
    while True:
        try:
            yield json.loads(buf)
        except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
            yield json.loads(buf[:err.pos])
            buf = buf[err.pos:]
        else:
            break
```

works with your demo data as:

```
with open('data.json') as fd:
    arr = list(json_load_all(fd.read()))
```

gives me exactly two elements, but I presume you have more?

to complete this using the standard library, writing out would look something like:

```
with open('data.json') as inp, open('out.json', 'w') as out:
    for obj in json_load_all(inp.read()):
        json.dump(obj, out)
        print(file=out)
```

otherwise the [`jsonlines`](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package is good for dealing with this data format

Answer (score 0):

Following [@Chris A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10201580/chris-a)'s comment, I've prepared this snippet which should work just fine:

```py
with open('my_jsons.file') as file:
    json_string = file.read()

json_objects = re.sub('}\s*{', '}|!|{', json_string).split('|!|')
# replace |!| with whatever suits you best

for json_object in json_objects:
    print(json.loads(obj))
```

This example, however, will become worthless as soon as '}{' string appears in some value inside your JSON, so I strongly recommend using [@Sam Mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358308/sam-mason)'s solution